# Extract data from bag as variables in CPP

Tags: c++, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a imu bag file and I want to take linear acceleration values xyz in cpp in variables  so I could  integrate them twice to get position but I am new  at ROS and I do not know how  ? I hope my question is clear.
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207766/extract-data-from-bag-as-variables-in-cpp/) by [ozo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22191/ozo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

play bag file using `rosbag`

```
robag play xxxxx.bag --clock
```

it will publish all the topics in bags file.

Write subcriber in your code to get values.

check [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data#Examining_and_playing_the_bag_file) for more info

---

**Edit**

```
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("imu", 1000, &imuCallback, this);    

void Callback(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr& msg)
{
    
    double lax = msg->linear_acceleration.x;
    double lay = msg->linear_acceleration.y;
    double laz= msg->linear_acceleration.z;   
}
```

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2015-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ozo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22191/ozo/) on 2015-04-24**:
Thank you for your answer but my problem is after subscribing how to make this for example double x=linear_acceleration.x;

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2015-04-24**:
check the update

**Comment by [ozo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22191/ozo/) on 2015-04-24**:
Thank you very much. It worked